# Silverlight 4 WebClient, unable to set HttpRequestHeader.ContentType to application/json

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, wcf

I've been struggling with this for far too long so I decided to post the question.

I have a MVC 3 RC2 site which hosts a WCF zero config endpoint, the website itself, and a SL 4 application. When the SL app uses the WeClient object to pull down data from the endpoint, the data is coming back as xml (the default unless told otherwise) When I try to change the headers with this snippet

```
        var client = new WebClient();
        var uri = new Uri("http://example.com/Services/GetFoodDescriptionsLookup(2100)");


        // A WebClient instance does not send optional HTTP headers by default. 
        // If your request requires an optional header, 
        // you must add the header to the Headers collection.

        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webheadercollection.aspx

        // WRONG
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";

        // RIGHT
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/json";

        client.DownloadProgressChanged += (o, e) =>
            {
                Status = String.Format("BytesReceived : {0}", e.BytesReceived);
            };

        client.DownloadStringCompleted += (o, e) =>
            {
                Status = "Downloading...Done.";
                Result = e.Result;
            };

        client.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
```

I receive "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object." , if I remove it, the call succeeds but comes back as xml.

The essence of my question is "How do I change the content type to application/json so that the wcf service can return JSON"? The endpoint works as I can use jQuery to pull down the correct format in a web browser.

Thank you,
Stephen

**EDIT**

I've since learned from Glenn Block that I was doing this all wrong, both in this example, and in this one with the HttpWebRequest class [How do I use HttpWebRequest GET method w/ ContentType="application/json"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644097/how-do-i-use-httpwebrequest-get-method-w-contenttype-application-json) Content type is used used to indicate what you plan on sending to the server, accept is what you expect to get back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use WebRequest instead of WebClient.

WebRequest has a ContentType property that can be used to set the content type.

Comment: Michael, so you're telling me it's not possible to use the WebClient in this fashion?

Comment: Correct, see the documentation for the WebHeaderCollection class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webheadercollection(VS.95).aspx

Comment: Thanks Michael! Can't believe I missed that section at the bottom, you know the one titled "Restricted Headers". Must have read that page 3 times before I posted... Mystery Solved, thanks.