# How do I use HttpWebRequest GET method w/ ContentType="application/json"

Tags: silverlight, wcf, json, httpwebrequest

This one is real simple, run this Silverlight4 example with the ContentType property commented out and you'll get back a response from from my service in xml. Now uncomment the property and run it and you'll get an ProtocolViolationException, what should happen is the service returns JSON formatted data.

```
#if DEBUG
                Address = "http://localhost.:55437/Services/GetFoodDescriptionsLookup(2100)";
#else
                Address = "http://stephenpattenconsulting.com/Services/GetFoodDescriptionsLookup(2100)";
#endif

Uri httpSite = new Uri(Address);

HttpWebRequest wreq = 
(HttpWebRequest)WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp.Create(httpSite);

//wreq.ContentType = "application/json"; // Wrong
wreq.Accept = "application/json"; // Right

wreq.BeginGetResponse((cb) =>
{
    HttpWebRequest rq = cb.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
    HttpWebResponse resp = rq.EndGetResponse(cb) as HttpWebResponse; // Exception
    StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
    string result =  rdr.ReadToEnd(); 
    rdr.Close();
}, wreq);
```

New exception

System.NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code
  Message=""
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
       at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at com.patten.silverlight.ViewModels.WebRequestLiteViewModel.b_*0(IAsyncResult cb)
       at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c*_DisplayClassd.b__b(Object state2)
       at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
       at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
       at System.Threading.*ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
  InnerException: System.NotSupportedException
       Message=Specified method is not supported.
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c*_DisplayClass5.b_*4(Object sendState)
            at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c*_DisplayClass2.b__0(Object sendState)
       InnerException:

**WORKING NOW**

The exception that I was getting was due to a hack I use to get Fiddler to show the loop-back adapter i.e. http://localhost.:55437/Services/GetFoodDescriptionsLookup(2100), notice the extra DOT after the word localhost.

**That was it!**

I know what everyone is thinking, this could have been solved it I would have included some of these details.. like the debug flag that changes the URI, I removed most of the code to make it easier to read on SO, thinking that the problem was in the networking stack. Hard lesson(s) learned.

Thanks to everyone who took the time to get involved with this, both on stackoverflow and offline.

For completeness I have added the jQuery function that had me thinking this whole time I needed to be setting "content-type" instead of "accept" when in the SL4 application. (READ THE DOCS!)

```
function CallService(serviceUrl, data, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: serviceUrl,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        contextType: "application/json", 
        cache: false,
        success: callback,
        error: function (msg) {
            alert("Request Failed!");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please post the request & response headers from Fiddler; also, what exactly is the exception? I mean, what is the message and inner exception.

Comment: Does the new exception in your edit come with the exact same code you posted above? Because I tried it and it worked without any problems, so I am surprised. Can you post a Fiddler log of your Silverlight application's call when this happens? (i.e. not a manual request created in Fiddler). An exception would arise at that location if you were using this web service cross-domain (because there is no policy file present) but not the exception you posted, so I assume that is not the issue; just to be sure - is your client application also on the same domain? (http://stephenpattenconsulting.com)

Comment: Yes, the exception is thrown when creating the HttpWebResponse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stephen, setting the content type is to allow SENDING JSON, not receiving it. There are several ways to do this. You can support both JSON and XML or only JSON. If all you want to do is support JSON then you can do this by setting the ResponseFormat property on the WebGet attribute for the service operation.

If you want to support both JSON and XML then you need to either enable automatic format selection on the service and send an accept header of "application/json", otherwise you 
can use a format string parameter in the query string and have the service use the WebOperationContext.OutgoingResponse.Format property.

Here's a [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/01/18/automatic-and-explicit-format-selection-in-wcf-webhttp-services.aspx) that covers various ways to do this from the server side. If you go the route of supporting automatic format selection then you need to set the [accept](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.accept.aspx) header of the HttpWebRequest to "application/json"

Comment: I have added the exception details to the post too.

Answer (score 1):

If you finally determine that it's a problem in the Silverlight HttpWebRequest, i.e., it might have a bug or excessively stupid security check in it that keeps it from handling text/json responses, one reasonable (if annoying) workaround might be to shell out to javascript to make the request, using the XMLHttpRequest object, and then return the results to Silverlight.  Annoying, but possible.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried specifying client (rather than browser) HTTP handling?  See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd920295(VS.95).aspx.  I know that there are some significant differences as to how the two methods work, and this could conceivably be one of them.  Just a random thought.

Comment: Ken, I would have missed it too, but if you look at the first line of code, you might notice something different than the normal WebRequest factory, this IS the Client (OS) networking stack being instantiated via the WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp.Create. Good idea, but doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, good point.  Well, to ask the obvious question, have you tried it the other way, using the browser HTTP stack?

Answer (score 1):

Glenn Block's answer already seems to say this but I guess it was not clear enough.

*The Content-Type header tells what type of data is in a POST body or HTTP response body*

**Your HTTP request is not either of these**. It is a GET request without any body. This is why you are getting a protocol violation exception - GET requests cannot have a Content-Type header because by definition they do not have any content.

Your Fiddler request is working simply because WCF is very accomodating to buggy clients. The error is coming from inside the Silverlight networking stack, which refuses to send a broken request.

Let's take it from the top: you want to get back JSON data. This is accomplished using the *Accept* header, which tells the server what kind of data you want to get back. Therefore, replace this

```
wreq.ContentType = "application/json";
```

with this

```
wreq.Accept = "application/json";
```

and you will get JSON data from the server.

Comment: Sander, I would have accepted his answer if it had not led to another issue which we have taken off-line. I'll clean this up with our findings later.. Thank you.

Comment: Sander is correct as long as the server supports content negotiation. In WCF this happens if you set the AutomaticFormattingEnabled switch on the binding.

Comment: Yes, Automatic Formatting is turned on, that's why I am bent on changing the accept header to application/json. FYI, now I've made it past the protocol exception I'm getting a new one, posted it above.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the details for the WCF End point? If it is returning XAML, the only way to get JSON is if it is configured to. The initial request simply requests a URL, it is not specifying a "mode" so I'm assuming the WCF is defaulting to XML. There should either be a specific endpoint to go to for JSON responses, or a setting on the WCF to return those only.

Comment: Changing the content type is enough for the endpoint to differentiate what format to return. Default is GET XML, but if you issue a GET with a contenttype of application/json then wcf will return json formatted data. Here is a link to the help page that is generated automatically by the runtime http://stephenpattenconsulting.com/Services/help/operations/GetFoodDescriptionsLookup

Comment: I should clarify this Jeremy. I first started this exercise with a client-side web page that used jQuery to hit the service. The way in which I set this call up is what got me stuck on the content type being what was needed to be set in order for the automatic formatting to kick in and return json. You know you're responsible for this, don't you. :)