# Invoking JSP from Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, http, jsp

We have a website developed in Java, JSP runs in a apache server.

For Usability reasons it was decided to design a Silverlight web application and invoke the JSP URLs from silverlight

http requests such as http://mydomain.myapp.com/transaction/transactionlist.jsp would return the response in JSON format.

I was thinking that its possible to invoke these JSP URLs from Silverlight using System.web.httprequest and associated classes and parse the JSON response using the .net JSON base classes.

But I just want to know if this approach is correct.

I tried invoking a JSP url and the moment I got an Protocol Violation exception saying a generic "The operation is not valid due to the current state of the object. Did not find any other information that can help me. Any comments/Guidance is really appreciated.

Comment: I have no idea about silverlight, but on applets you're (by default) disallowed to fire HTTP requests to other domain than where the applet is been downloaded from. Maybe similar restriction exist in silverlight? This is by the way not a JSP problem (although you've a design problem; returning non-HTML content should be done by a servlet, not by a JSP)

Comment: @BalusC Yes. You are right. Based on your comment I explored further and it looks like I can make http calls to the resources that exists in the same domain from where my silverlight application gets downloaded from. But I can override by creating files like ClientAccessPolicy.xml. Thanks for guiding in a right way!!!

Comment: In other words, your concrete problem is now solved? Or do you still get this exception and was this thus related to something else? If your concrete problem is actually solved because you was indeed firing the request on a different domain, then let me know if I need to repost the comment as an answer.

Comment: @BalusC Yes you can do that. However I can mark Ken's answer as useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644097/how-do-i-use-httpwebrequest-get-method-w-contenttype-application-json) question.  It's certainly possible to do what you're doing, but you need to get the HttpWebRequest configured correctly.  Specifically:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://mydomain.myapp.com/transaction/transactionlist.jsp");
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp.Create(uri);
webRequest.Accept = "application/json";  // Key
```